# ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection:

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code, selenium-chromedriver, python-behave

While running Python code using behave Framework in visual code for selenium Automation

logs are:

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57159/devtools/browser/4787574a-1842-48dd-a69e-919739ddf21a
[14332:16524:1120/113508.444:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [11:35:08.444] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[14332:16524:1120/113508.446:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [11:35:08.447] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[14332:16524:1120/113508.478:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [11:35:08.478] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[6492:11676:1120/113533.910:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -113
[6492:11676:1120/113533.998:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -113[image]

Comment: I'm also been having a similar problem in the last few days with these errors `USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)` and this one too `USB: usb_service_win.cc:352 Could not get child device's service name: Element not found. (0x490)`

Comment: Same here, i believe it`s related to chrome/chromedriver version 87, its was ok a couple of weeks ago. I haven't found a solution so far. What versions are you using?

Comment: @soundwave : this error cames when USB connected with Computer and we trying to run code in Visual code.

Comment: @RiteshToppo I'm not using visual studio though, just cmd in windows

Comment: @rodrigorf I'm using version 87.0.4280.20 of chromedriver

Comment: I am also getting kind of this in the output terminal window although everything seems to work fine but I am worried if this can cause any complication in future during production phase.

Comment: You can ignore these error as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/65081791/5324105 "They are triggered by Chrome attempting to read properties of USB devices that are currently suspended."