# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm getting started with Selenium using Javascript. I tried the following code:

```js
const webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver"),
  By = webdriver.By;

const driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();

driver.get("http://www.google.com");

driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("webdriver");

driver.sleep(1000).then(function () {
  driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(webdriver.Key.TAB);
});

driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click();

driver.sleep(2000).then(function () {
  driver.getTitle().then(function (title) {
    if (title === "webdriver - Google Search") {
      console.log("Test passed");
    } else {
      console.log("Test failed");
    }
    driver.quit();
  });
});
```

I am getting the following error:

> $ node google_test
>
> DevTools listening on
> ws://127.0.0.1:60706/devtools/browser/74ff1ebf-908a-4f60-973c-95507cade998
> Test failed (node:2796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
> ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable   (Session info:
> chrome=87.0.4280.66)
> at Object.throwDecodedError (C:\Users\x\selenium-test\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:550:15)
> at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\x\selenium-test\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:565:13)
> at Executor.execute (C:\Users\x\selenium-test\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:491:26)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
> at async thenableWebDriverProxy.execute (C:\Users\x\selenium-test\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:700:17)
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was
> created) (node:2796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of
> an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise
> which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on
> unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag
> `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1) (node:2796) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.

When I use this code, it kind of works, but I get different error:

```
const webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver"),
  By = webdriver.By,
  until = webdriver.until;

const driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();

driver.get("http://www.google.com/ncr");

var query = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.name("q")));
query.sendKeys("webdriver\n");

driver.wait(until.titleContains("webdriver - Google"));
```

The error:

> $ [12612:12448:1202/120322.598:ERROR:usb_descriptors.cc(160)] Device
> descriptor parsing error.
> [12612:12448:1202/120322.599:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)]
> [12:03:22.599] USB: usb_device_win.cc:93 Failed to read descriptors
> from
> \?\usb#vid_413c&pid_2113#70000030#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}.
> [12612:12448:1202/120322.600:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)]
> [12:03:22.600] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read
> descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is
> not functioning. (0x1F)
> [12612:12448:1202/120322.607:ERROR:usb_descriptors.cc(160)] Device
> descriptor parsing error.
> [12612:12448:1202/120322.608:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)]
> [12:03:22.608] USB: usb_device_win.cc:93 Failed to read descriptors
> from
> \?\usb#vid_0424&pid_2807&asmediausbd_hub#00000830#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}. [12612:12448:1202/120322.620:ERROR:usb_descriptors.cc(160)] Device
> descriptor parsing error.
> [12612:12448:1202/120322.621:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)]
> [12:03:22.621] USB: usb_device_win.cc:93 Failed to read descriptors
> from
> \?\usb#vid_0bda&pid_8153#000001000000#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}.
> [12612:12448:1202/120322.623:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)]
> [12:03:22.623] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read
> descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is
> not functioning. (0x1F)

Please help me understand what's going wrong?

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/65081791/5324105 you can ignore the second error log. May be it will be turned off in next release

Comment: ok i will use the 2nd code, but how do i `quit()` afterwards? i get another error when i add `driver.quit()`?

Comment: Refer https://help.crossbrowsertesting.com/selenium-testing/getting-started/javascript/ You will need to understand async /await in Javascript

Comment: thanks for the link, i was able to run the script for chrome, but it fails for firefox, looks like enter is not pressed and the page title is the old one: https://hastebin.com/igevicepaw.js