# Failed to read descriptor from node connection in Protractor with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, protractor, yarnpkg

When I'm trying to fetch the values from the database, I have received the below error. But the DB connection was a success.

ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [08:19:41.497] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor  from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65081791/9150146