# Selenium webdriver dns_config_watch_failed and usb not functioning Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, dns, driver

I'm running selenium webdriver on windows10 Python 3.8.6 using chrome. I'm not sure how to check but I think I'm using chrome driver version 88. In my script I'm using the following Chrome options:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
prefs = {
"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
"download.default_directory": fr"{dwnld_dir}",
"directory_upgrade": True,
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)  # preferences set
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")`:
```

where `dwnld_dir` is the directory to download to. The script runs fine but with 2 x error messages at the start:

```
:ERROR:dns_config_services_win.cc(785)] DNS config watch failed
:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211) [07:24:12.130] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

How can I resolve these errors?

**UPDATE**

[Debanjanb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7429447/debanjanb) provides a detailed solution to the [USB Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio) here. This should be resolved soon in later updates.

For the DNS error, here is the link to source docs [dns_config_service_winc.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/dns/dns_config_service_win.cc) and below function producing the error:

```
void DnsConfigServiceWin::OnConfigChanged(bool succeeded) {
  InvalidateConfig();
  config_reader_->WorkNow();
  if (!succeeded) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "DNS config watch failed.";
    set_watch_failed(true);
    UMA_HISTOGRAM_ENUMERATION("AsyncDNS.WatchStatus",
                              DNS_CONFIG_WATCH_FAILED_CONFIG,
                              DNS_CONFIG_WATCH_MAX);
  }
```

Still not sure if DNS_CONFIG_WATCH_FAILED_CONFIG poses security risk though.

Comment: remove "--allow-running-insecure-content" to see if the error goes away.  (It's probably about that and some fairly recent changes in Chrome regarding mixed content...http/https)

Comment: Thanks @pcalkins. Your solution worked. I just skimmed through some more docs and the USB messages mostly happen with Windows and won't show up from version 90.

Answer (score 1):

[pcalkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744568/pcalkins) suggestion worked - remove `options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")` this resolves the DNS error message. Newer chrome versions are aiming to resolve the USB error message too.