# USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am having problem with Selenium Chromedriver. I am using chrome V88 and same version for the webdriver. I am getting error USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. The browser will not bring up my webpage. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have the same problem error message  but the browser and everything else is working OK, so whatever is causing the error message is not necessarily fatal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB: usb\_device\_handle\_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection error with ChromeDriver v87 / Chrome v87 using Selenium on Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio)

Answer (score 1):

See same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio). "If you aren't having issues connecting to a device with WebUSB you can ignore these warnings. They are triggered by Chrome attempting to read properties of USB devices that are currently suspended."