# How to suppress warnings from webbot?

Tags: python, webbot

I made a really simple script with Webbot to access a page, it works fine but there are some warnings I'd like to suppress.

From what I've looked they are from the ChromeDriver but I have no idea how to deal with them.

```
form webbot import Browser

web = Browser()
web.go_to('https://randomwebpage.com/')
web.type('something', into='field')
web.type('something', into='field')
web.press(web.Key.ENTER)

web.click(text=f'{clase}')
```

It does works but it throws these warnings

```
[23808:15436:0415/220125.376:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [22:01:25.376] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1054 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: 
Uno de los dispositivos conectados al sistema no funciona. (0x1F)
[23808:15436:0415/220125.381:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [22:01:25.381] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1054 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: 
Uno de los dispositivos conectados al sistema no funciona. (0x1F)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB: usb\_device\_handle\_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection error with ChromeDriver v87 / Chrome v87 using Selenium on Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio)

Comment: not really but thank you anyways. I'll just clear the screen right after the warnings