# new to protractor and using visual studio code and getting this on command line

Tags: javascript, protractor

ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [17:03:17.669] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1054 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)

Comment: post your protractor, webdriver-manager, chrome, chromedriver versions

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio