# Selenium Error: USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1058 Failed to read descriptor from node connection

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Right below is my code, I want to get the *amount of searching* from google by enter certain keywords (right here is **data["Event_Name"]** in my code) .

Btw, I'm using vscode to write this project.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\Users\domin\Desktop\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
                               
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.find_element_by_id("input").send_keys(data["Event_Name"])
driver.find_element_by_class_name("icon").click()
importance_fresh = driver.find_element_by_id("result-stats").text
driver.quit()
```

But I kept receiving the error like this:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62480/devtools/browser/0d1cf75e-d21b-4648-958c-6f291e6c6e3e
[9924:21508:0613/202733.993:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [20:27:33.993] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1058 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[9924:21508:0613/202733.997:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [20:27:33.998] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1058 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

How should I do next to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB: usb\_device\_handle\_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection error with ChromeDriver v87 / Chrome v87 using Selenium on Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio)

Answer (score 1):

See same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio). "If you aren't having issues connecting to a device with WebUSB you can ignore these warnings. They are triggered by Chrome attempting to read properties of USB devices that are currently suspended."