# Watir Error - Unable to run Watir code example

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir, faker

On running the following script from http://watir.com/guides/form-example/, I get an error:

```
# Require the gems we want to use
require 'watir'
require 'webdrivers'
require 'faker'

# Initialize the Browser
browser = Watir::Browser.new

# Navigate to Page
browser.goto 'watir.com/examples/simple_form.html'

# Fill out Text Field Names
browser.text_field(id: 'first_name').set 'Luke'
browser.text_field(id: 'last_name').set 'Perry'

# Use Random Email Address via Faker gem
# Read more about Faker gem here: https://github.com/stympy/faker#readme
random_email = Faker::Internet.email
browser.text_field(id: 'email').set random_email

# Select List:
browser.select(id: 'country').select 'Norway'

# Checkboxes:
browser.checkbox(id: 'interests_cars').click
browser.checkbox(id: 'interests_dentistry').click

# Radio Button:
browser.radio(id: 'newsletter_no').click

# Use RadioSet instead of Radio Button:
browser.radio_set(name: 'newsletter').select('Yes')

# Click Button:
browser.button(id: 'submitButton').click

# Evaluate Results:
browser.p(id: 'name').text == 'Hello Luke Perry,' # => true
browser.p(id: 'newsletter').text == "You will be receiving our newsletter at #{random_email}" # => true
browser.p(id: 'activities').text == 'We hope you continue to enjoy cars, dentistry in Norway' # => true
```

Here is the error:

> DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61657/devtools/browser/97a9134d-96bb-47f6-83e8-56f09555e71e
> [8472:12912:0826/150047.561:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:00:47.561] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
> [8472:12912:0826/150047.589:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:00:47.589] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)>

Any ideas for running the script successfully?

Thanks

Comment: What version selenium, watir, chrome?

Comment: Looking at the gem folder, it says "selenium-webdriver-3.142.7". Chrome Version is 92.0.4515.159 and Watir version is 6.19.1. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary there. What is the stack trace?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge here. How can I find the stack trace?

Comment: How are you executing this code? Irb? RSpec? Rb file?

Comment: Oh I see. I am running it in the command prompt using "ruby watir-example.rb"

Comment: Here is some more info in case it might help. After running the script, the page comes up with the form and it fills out all the info in it. The error messages come when the form is almost half way complete. The page closes after the form is completed.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, based on the clarification everything is working as intended, there's just some extra noise in the console output based on "Chrome attempting to read properties of USB devices that are currently suspended."

You can safely ignore this message.

Look here for more information:
[USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection error with ChromeDriver v87 / Chrome v87 using Selenium on Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio)

Comment: This is definitely a Chrome issue because I was able to run the script successfully using Firefox and got the expected result. 

"Response
Hello Luke Perry,

You will be receiving our newsletter at denae@lockman.info

We hope you continue to enjoy cars, dentistry in Norway" . 

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: @msjanjua I think you should have gotten the same result on the page in Chrome, just with extra output in stdout? Or is it exiting the code early?

Comment: It exits the code early and closes the page. In Firefox, the page stays open with the expected results.

Comment: ok, that's a little different. Can you set $DEBUG=true at the beginning, put the result in https://gist.github.com/ and reply with a link?

Comment: I put $DEBUG=true at the very beginning of my script and got these results: https://gist.github.com/msjanjua/1858f6f068df280414378a743dd9709c

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Ah, ok. The logs show that the values expected from the results page showed up. But when the ruby program completes it quits the driver, and when the driver quits it closes the browser. If you copy the lines in irb, you'll see the results, or you can put a `sleep(10)` at the end and see it for 10 seconds before it goes away.

Comment: Yes, that worked! I put sleep(10) at the end of my script and the browser stayed open for ten seconds. I will ignore the error messages about "a device attached to the system is not functioning". Thanks.