# How to supress the usb and bluetooth driver errors setting up Selenium ChromeDriver and Chrome,?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, usb

New user to python here, I'm trying some webscraping with Selenium. The code executes correctly however there are a few things that come up in the log, should I be concerned about them and where can I find the solution to these errors?

```
[12592:15880:0416/191306.015:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [19:13:06.014] USB: usb_service_win.cc:391 Could not read device interface GUIDs: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[12592:15880:0416/191306.018:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [19:13:06.017] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[12592:15880:0416/191306.028:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [19:13:06.027] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[12592:15880:0416/191306.036:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [19:13:06.035] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1075 Getting Default Adapter failed.
```

I'm running windows 10, installed the latest python (3.10.4) and chromedriver (Latest stable release: 100.0.4896.60)

Here's my helloworld code, if it helps:

```
# import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys #for interaction so you can search inputs and press buttons
import time

# PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

PATH=Service('C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=PATH)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

search = driver.find_element_by_name("q") #find an input with this name
search.send_keys("pink sandals")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) #like pressing enter

time.sleep(5)

# driver.close() #close current tab
driver.quit() #close entire browser
```

P.S. I am using deprecated keywords cause I've only checked out one tutorial so far (published in 2020) so I'm still learning the ropes.

Answer (score 1):

This error messages...

```
[12592:15880:0416/191306.015:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [19:13:06.014] USB: usb_service_win.cc:391 Could not read device interface GUIDs: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[12592:15880:0416/191306.018:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [19:13:06.017] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[12592:15880:0416/191306.028:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [19:13:06.027] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[12592:15880:0416/191306.036:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [19:13:06.035] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1075 Getting Default Adapter failed.
```

are triggered as  [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) attempts to read properties of USB devices that are currently suspended and you can ignore those warnings if you are not facing any issues connecting to a device with WebUSB.

> You can find a relevant detailed discssion in [USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection error with ChromeDriver v87 / Chrome v87 using Selenium on Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65080685/7429447)

---

### Solution

To supress these messages from appearing on the console you can add the following *`experimental option`*:

```
add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
```

as follows:

> [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) compatible code block

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
PATH=Service('C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=PATH, options=options)
```