# Python web scraping is stuck with 2 error messages

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm doing my school project and is trying to scrape data from websites using Python. I followed a tutorial on edureka - https://www.edureka.co/blog/web-scraping-with-python/#demo

This is the sample code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\COSC2625_Team_Blue\chromedriver")

products=[] #List to store name of the product
prices=[] #List to store price of the product
ratings=[] #List to store rating of the product
driver.get("""<a href="https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/">https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/</a>~buyback-guarantee-on-laptops-/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;uniq""")

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for a in soup.findAll('a',href=True, attrs={'class':'_31qSD5'}):
    name=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_3wU53n'})
    price=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK'})
    rating=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'hGSR34 _2beYZw'})
    products.append(name.text)
    prices.append(price.text)
    ratings.append(rating.text) 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Product Name':products,'Price':prices,'Rating':ratings}) 
df.to_csv('products.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

After running the code, a blank web browser shown up, and there is a error message in the terminal -

```
PS D:\COSC2625_Team_Blue> [8556:2544:0809/132114.260:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [13:21:14.260] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

I searched this online and somebody said that it doesn't stop the code from running, so I waited for a while and another message appeared.

```
[4488:14404:0809/132312.207:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(486)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

Then the whole programme is stuck, I waited for an hour but there are still these 2 messages, and the blank web browser is still there.

Does anyone know what happened here?

Comment: `webdriver.get` needs to be passed a URL to fetch.  Just do `driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/")`.

Answer (score 0):

None of these log messages...

```
PS D:\COSC2625_Team_Blue> [8556:2544:0809/132114.260:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [13:21:14.260] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

or

```
[4488:14404:0809/132312.207:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(486)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

should be any sort of blockers as these *`warnings`* are triggered by Chrome attempting to read properties of USB devices that are currently suspended. You can safely ignore them.

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection error with ChromeDriver v87 / Chrome v87 using Selenium on Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65080685/7429447)

---

### get()

[get(url: str)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get) method accepts an *`url_string`* as an argument and loads the web page in the current browser session. So essentially you need to pass the *`url_string`* as follows:

```
driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/')
```