# Hello I am trying to learn selenium and I have an error

Tags: python, selenium

I try to print all the elements of my page but when I want to print them it puts me this how can I solve this problem?

My code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# declancher le driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.kubii.fr/ ")

# recupérer la bar de recherche
search_bar = driver.find_element(By.ID, "search_query_top")
# envoyer la recherche dans la bar de recherche (Raspberry)
search_bar.send_keys("Raspberry")

# lancer la recherche 
search_btn = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "submit_search")
# cliquer sur le bouton de recherche
search_btn.click()

# recuperer tout les nom des produit 
all_titles = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-info")

print(all_titles)
```

My `print(all_titles)`

```py
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:18480/devtools/browser/e099595e-55ac-406a-ba70-81aa80a74276
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="770103c986f8e6a792a86a9ebfd793a7", element="f3ca0f43-b3e0-44ce-8f61-5e2b3d865a83")>
PS C:\Users\victo\OneDrive\Bureau\Devlopement\python\ScrapingTest> [15156:3312:0816/010238.862:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [01:02:38.861] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Un pÚriphÚrique attachÚ au systÞme ne fonctionne pas correctement. (0x1F)
[15156:3312:0816/010238.867:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [01:02:38.866] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Un pÚriphÚrique attachÚ au systÞme ne fonctionne pas correctement. (0x1F)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB: usb\_device\_handle\_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection error with ChromeDriver v87 / Chrome v87 using Selenium on Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio)

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#declencher le driver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
# to supress the error messages/logs
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.kubii.fr/ ")
```

it's not related to selenium rather the driver reading USB properties.
you can find more explanations in this answer :
[USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection error with ChromeDriver v87 / Chrome v87 using Selenium on Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio)