# Trying to scrap the website using selenium but getting this error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

```
type hefrom selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

s=Service('I:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
path='I:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'

#Website to scrap
website='https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed'


driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=chrome_options)
driver.get(website)


#Locating and clicking an element
all_matches_button=driver.find_element(by='xpath',value="//label[normalize-space()='All matches']").click()


matches=driver.find_elements(by="xpath",value='tr')
for match in matches:
    print(match.text)
```

Error:"USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1045 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)" and "Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed."

A soultion to my problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB: usb\_device\_handle\_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection error with ChromeDriver v87 / Chrome v87 using Selenium on Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio)

Answer (score 0):

1. how did you get usb error and bluetooth? whats going on?
2. `type hefrom selenium import webdriver` where from you copy pasted?
3. variable `all_matches_button` never used in your code and there is no need to save anything to variable when click on element.

   ```
   #Locating and clicking an element
   all_matches_button=driver.find_element(by='xpath',value="//label[normalize-space()='All matches']").click()
   ```
4. here is working code to start dig deeper

   ```
   from time import sleep

   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

   chrome_options = Options()
   chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

   website = 'https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed'

   driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
   driver.get(website)
   sleep(4)

   tr_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tr")
   for tr in tr_elements:

       print(tr.tag_name, tr.get_attribute('textContent'))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

however, this message shouldn't prevent you from getting scraping result. try to correct your xpath in the last line by adding slashes

```
matches=driver.find_elements(by="xpath",value='//tr')
```