# USB: usb_service_win.cc:415 Could not read device interface GUIDs: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**My Code:**

```py
from selenium import webdriver  
import time
    
web = webdriver.Chrome()
web.get('https://fs30.formsite.com/LB2014/wa03ei3cqi/index.html')
    
time.sleep(2)
    
FirstName = "Test"     
first = web.find_element('xpath', "//*[@id='RESULT_TextField-4']")
first.send_keys(FirstName)
```

**Error in Powershell:**

> ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [14:44:23.883] USB:
> usb_service_win.cc:415 Could not read device interface GUIDs: The
> system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

New to selenium and using python for automation. I tried looking up my error but couldn't find anyone with the same problem. Does anyone know what I need to do or have any pointers?

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio

Comment: @pcalkins Hey, thanks for the link. I read through this twice and didn't really understand it. Could you help me out in understanding it? I am running Windows 11

Comment: It's just something logged from the browser.  No need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about, it's just a warning from the browser.
If you want to prevent it from appearing you can add this option:

```
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
```