# Robot Framework - Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I have very specific problem with my root framework. Can not run tests in ChromeDriver.

My Chrome version is: 118.0.5993.89
My WebDriver Version is: 118.0.5993.70

When I start the tests, the web browser is open but page is not loaded.
I have "data:," displayed as web browser address.

Here are my logs:

```
Started: C:\Users\gzru\Desktop\robot-framework-template-main\robot-framework-template-main\tests\UI\01_sample_testcase.robot
==============================================================================
01 Sample Testcase :: Test file containing sample UI testcase and code exam...
==============================================================================
[info] I run before each suite
[info] Check all texts in log file
[info] Creating an instance of the Chrome WebDriver.
[info] Applicable driver not found; attempting to install with Selenium Manager (Beta)
[ WARN ] Incompatible release of chromedriver (version 118.0.5993.70) detected in PATH: C:\Users\gzru\Desktop\Driver\chromedriver.exe
[WARN (+0.82s)] Incompatible release of chromedriver (version 118.0.5993.70) detected in PATH: C:\Users\gzru\Desktop\Driver\chromedriver.exe
[info (+3.98s)] Cannot capture screenshot because no browser is open.
[FAIL] WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0065A813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x005EC4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x004F5358]
    (No symbol) [0x00513621]
    (No symbol) [0x00510579]
    (No symbol) [0x00540C55]
    (No symbol) [0x0054093C]
    (No symbol) [0x0053A536]
    (No symbol) [0x005182DC]
    (No symbol) [0x005193DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x008BAABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x008FA78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x008F456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006E51E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x005F5F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x005F2328]
    (No symbol) [0x005F240B]
    (No symbol) [0x005E4FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75CCFCC9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FE7C6E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FE7C3E+238]

01 Check If Women Section Can Be Opened                               | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0065A813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x005EC4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x004F5358]
    (No symbol) [0x00513621]
    (No symbol) [0x00510579]
    (No symbol) [0x00540C55]
    (No symbol) [0x0054093C]
    (No symbol) [0x0053A536]
    (No symbol) [0x005182DC]
    (No symbol) [0x005193DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x008BAABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x008FA78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x008F456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006E51E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x005F5F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x005F2328]
    (No symbol) [0x005F240B]
    (No symbol) [0x005E4FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75CCFCC9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FE7C6E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FE7C3E+238]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01 Sample Testcase :: Test file containing sample UI testcase and ... | FAIL |
Suite setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0065A813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x005EC4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x004F5358]
    (No symbol) [0x00513621]
    (No symbol) [0x00510579]
    (No symbol) [0x00540C55]
    (No symbol) [0x0054093C]
    (No symbol) [0x0053A536]
    (No symbol) [0x005182DC]
    (No symbol) [0x005193DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x008BAABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x008FA78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x008F456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006E51E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x005F5F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x005F2328]
    (No symbol) [0x005F240B]
    (No symbol) [0x005E4FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75CCFCC9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FE7C6E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FE7C3E+238]


1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
[info] I run after each suite
Output:  C:\Users\gzru\Desktop\robot-framework-template-main\log\output.xml
[info] It is important to put here actions that will tidy up after tests
Log:     C:\Users\gzru\Desktop\robot-framework-template-main\log\log.html
Report:  C:\Users\gzru\Desktop\robot-framework-template-main\log\report.html

Robot Run Terminated (code: 0)
```

Here is the code of my test which I want to run.

```
*** Test Cases ***
01 Check If Women Section Can Be Opened
    Open Women Section
```

In this way I'm starting the driver. Chrome driver is in folder and is added to path

```
*** Variables ***
${main_Url}         https://magento.softwaretestingboard.com/
${browser}          Chrome

*** Keywords ***
Open Main Page
    Set Selenium Speed    1
    Open Browser     ${main_Url}     ${browser}
    Set Window Size    1600     1200
    Wait Until Page Contains        Sale
```

I tried to run no web browser related tests and it works ok so installation of robot seems to be ok.
I tried to install other webdriver 118.0.5993.88 but the results are the same.

Comment: Hi, haven't your issue disappeared after system reboot or closing/killing all Chrome and Chromedriver instances?

Comment: Hi, after rebooting it is still not working but I noticed a new Error in logs which I did not seen before
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55260/devtools/browser/b3b1d2c1-d1e0-402a-a5c6-84e89702a902

[5876:5140:1023/190206.210:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(225)] [19:02:06.211] USB: usb_service_win.cc:415 Could not read device interface GUIDs: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

Comment: It seems [new error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75164611/usb-usb-service-win-cc415-could-not-read-device-interface-guids-the-system-ca) is not too serious. Until more qualified advice from experts, and before trying Chrome reinstalling, WDYT to make settings reset in Chrome?

Comment: I tried reinstalling Chrome but it does not helped.

Comment: Just in case what are your selenium and robotframework-seleniumlibrary versions?

Comment: I checked it also :) I think the problem is with my laptop. I moved repository to other pc and it is working correctly without any issues - configuration is exactly the same.