# Not able to get undetected-chromedriver.exe download file

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

Not able to get `undetected-chromedriver.exe` download file

I am using `undetected-chromedriver` in Python. I have installed `undetected-chromedriver` using `pip install undetected-chromedriver`

Below is my code

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
# Setting Driver Implicit Time out for An Element
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
# Maximize the window
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2000)
print("maxmized window")
driver.get("http://example.net")
```

Error I am getting with above code once browser is launched is as below

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65496/devtools/browser/a66dad5d-073d-478c-a291-e29a127a2ecb        
[15220:11524:0210/192501.116:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(218)] [19:25:01.116] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[15220:11524:0210/192501.123:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(218)] [19:25:01.123] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/#history

I need exe of undetected-chromedriver , can you please help

Also while instantiating I am getting can not find declaration, however I have installed `pip install undetected-chromedriver`
[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you got an exception?

Comment: Yes, It is not performing any action, it is just launching chrome browser but its kind of stuck

Comment: Where will I get exe for undetected-chrome?

Comment: If the browser launches, there isn't any other `.exe` file needed. Please specify wat you mean by "stuck"

Comment: Means it is not launching url

Comment: But i need exe as well.. launching is secondary issue..i have to use hard-coded exe of undetected chrome

Comment: So you're trying to compile your script as an `.exe` file? Or do you allready have issues when running it as a python script?

Comment: No i want o launch it from robot script and my requirement is different..i want to use undetected chrome with hard-coded exe path

Comment: Well  but your provided code is __Python__, not robo script, and also, using Python, I don't see any reason why you'd want to compile undetected-chromedriver as  executable file (.exe)

Comment: reason I am doing automation for one site which is only working chrome undetected driver ....normal chrome driver its giving site can not reach error....so I want use static driver exe for that

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii I have updated details in question with error which I am getting after launch of browser in console of python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251792/discussion-between-simond-and-kaliiiiiiiii).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB: usb\_device\_handle\_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection error with ChromeDriver v87 / Chrome v87 using Selenium on Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio)

Comment: No, it does not answer my question

Comment: But that's exactly the solution to the error-message you provided?

Comment: I did not find this chrome flag to enable -enable-new-usb-backend

Comment: Did you tri [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70476264/20443541) then?

Comment: Yes i tried it's not working..i tried enabling all flag and no usb connected to my machine..what else is solution?

Answer (score 0):

as when I tried to execute the script and using undetected-chromedriver it **does not require an executable** since it downloads the chromedriver and patches it

> Optimized Selenium Chromedriver patch which does not trigger anti-bot services like Distill Network / Imperva / DataDome / Botprotect.io Automatically downloads the driver binary and patches it.

source from [here](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver)