# Facing issue in python selenium - USB: usb_service_win.cc:415 Could not read device interface GUIDs: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When I tried running my python selenium code in pycharm i got following error -

```
USB: usb_service_win.cc:415 Could not read device interface GUIDs: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
```

I expect browser should open

Comment: this question will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio